# Get Other Columns based on window function maximum value, Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, max, window-functions

How to get the whole row or other column value for the same row for which window function in over clause gave output.

For ex.

```
with o as (
    select date from unnest(GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY('2021-01-01 00:00:00',current_timestamp(),interval 1 hour)) as date
enter code here
), p as (
    select *,RAND()*100 as Number from o
), q as (
    select *,max(number) over(order by date) as best from p
    order by date
)
select * from q
```

Using the above query I get output as the best value which defined the maximum number above me when order by timestamp.

The output of the above column :

[image: Query Output]

I calculated the best value using the over function, but I also want the date column on which day it was best.

Comment: I understand, that you need another column best_date for example (2021-01-01 21:00:00 UTC)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this one?

```
with o as (
    select date from unnest(GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY('2021-01-01 00:00:00',current_timestamp(),interval 1 hour)) as date
), p as (
    select *,RAND()*100 as Number from o
), q as (
    select *,max(number) over(order by date) as best from p
)
select * except(date_new_best), max(date_new_best) over (order by date) as date_best 
from (
    select *, if(number=best, date, NULL) as date_new_best
    from q
)
order by date
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Consider below approach

```
with o as (
    select date from unnest(GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY('2021-01-01 00:00:00',current_timestamp(),interval 1 hour)) as date
), p as (
    select *,RAND()*100 as Number from o
), q as (
    select *,max(number) over(order by date) as best from p
)
select * except(best_date),
  last_value(best_date ignore nulls) over(order by date) as best_date
from (
  select *, if(best = lag(best) over(order by date), null, date) best_date
  from q
)
```

with output like below

[image]